# Reading file and skipping whitespace?

Tags: c, file, while-loop, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to take a line from file and take the first word into an array and the rest into another array. But the SpanArray is empty always and i have no idea why.

My Function;

```
void arrayIni(char *fullArray, char *emptyArrayEng, char *emptyArraySpan)
{
    int counter= 0;
    while(1)
    {
        emptyArrayEng[counter] = fullArray[counter];
        counter++;
        if (isspace(fullArray[counter]) )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    counter++;
    while(1)
    {
        emptyArraySpan[counter] = fullArray[counter];
        printf("%c",fullArray[counter]);
        counter++;
        if (fullArray[counter] == '\n'){
            break;
        }
    }
    int printer=0;
}
```

Main where file is read;

```
int main() {
    int ch;
    char str[128], meaning[256];
    FILE *file = fopen("/Users/users/Desktop/mko/mko/txttt", "r");
    char array[300];
    while(fgets(array, 300, file))
        {
            arrayIni(array, str, meaning);
            insert(str, meaning);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must terminate each string with `'\0'`.

Comment: `emptyArraySpan[counter] =` : Use another counter.

Comment: try `sscanf(fullArray, "%s %[^\n]",  emptyArrayEng, emptyArraySpan);`

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems in your `arrayIni` function as I see it.

1. You are not terminating arrays with `'\0'`
2. The indexing of `emptyArraySpan` should be done with a different counter
3. Also, you should passing the length of the array `fullArray`, to arrayIni function and validate it against the counter to ensure there is no out-of-bounds access

.

```
void arrayIni(char *fullArray, int fullArrayLen, char *emptyArrayEng, char *emptyArraySpan)
{
    int counter= 0;
    int counter_1 = 0;

     while(counter < fullArrayLen)
     {
         emptyArrayEng[counter] = fullArray[counter];
         counter++;
         if (isspace(fullArray[counter]) )
         {
            break;
         }
      }

      emptyArrayEng[counter] = '\0';
      counter++;
      while(counter < fullArrayLen)
      {
         emptyArraySpan[counter_1] = fullArray[counter];
         printf("%c",fullArray[counter]);
         counter_1++;
         counter++;
         if (fullArray[counter] == '\n'){
                break;
           }
      }
      emptyArraySpan[counter_1] = '\0';
       int printer=0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example, I am writing code to split string into words; you can use this function in your program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TRUE 1

int getWords(char *base, char target[10][20])
{
    int n=0,i,j=0;

    for(i=0;TRUE;i++)
    {
        if(base[i]!=' '){
            target[n][j++]=base[i];
        }
        else{
            target[n][j++]='\0';//insert NULL
            n++;
            j=0;
        }
        if(base[i]=='\0')
            break;
    }
    return n;

}
int main()
{
    int n; //number of words
    int i; //loop counter 
    char str[]="This is Mike";
    char arr[10][20];

    n=getWords(str,arr);

    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
This
is
Mike
```